Notion's search api is returning the pages in wrong order
I'm using the notions search api and its returning the notion pages in a different order compared to the notion app
flask code ->
@app.route("/api/notion/pages", methods=["GET"])
def get_notion_pages():
    access_token = tokens.get("access_token")

    if not access_token:
        return jsonify({"success": False, "error": "Access token is missing"}), 400

    search_url = "https://api.notion.com/v1/search"
    headers = {
        "Authorization": f"Bearer {access_token}",
        "Notion-Version": "2022-06-28",
    }
    payload = {
        "query": "", 
               "filter": {
                    "value": "page",
                      "property": "object"
                },
                # "sort": {
                #     "direction": "ascending",
                #     "timestamp": "last_edited_time",
                # }
        }

    response = requests.post(search_url, json=payload, headers=headers)
    pages = response.json()
    logging.info(f"Pages: {pages['results']}")

    return jsonify(pages['results'])  

i've tried adding the direction of sorting as descending but that did not help the main purpose of this API is just to show users all of his page in the correct order so that he can choose what pages to go ahead with....
the actual order of the pages in my notion workspace

where as this is what notions has returned me the data as

main 1.2.1.1
main 1.2.1
main 1.3
main
main 1.1.1
main 1.1
main 1.2

does anyone know how to fix it, this is legit the starting point of the app and the order of the pages cannot go wrong as the next few steps and execution is literally dependent on the pages and the order of the pages returned
